# React Native Search Bar Issues

Tags: react-native, native-base

When I type A  on search Bar , it gives result set 1 
When I type Ap  on search Bar , it gives result set 2

When I type A , Ap , then backspace to A on search Bar , it gives result set 2 instead of result set 1

The below is my filter method on javascript. Would you please tell me what should I do ?

working :

```
  filter(text){     
     this.setState({ keywords: text })

     const newData = this.state.results.filter(function(item){
         const itemData = item.fruit_name.toUpperCase()
         const textData = text.toUpperCase()
         return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
     })

     if(text){
         this.setState({
            results: newData,
            text: text
         })
     }else{
        this.setState({
            results: this.state.oldresults,
            text: text
         })
     }   
 }
```

Data List UI : FlatList from react-native, ListItem from NativeBase

```
 <FlatList 
                  extraData={this.state}
                  data={this.state.results}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                  renderItem={( {item} ) => {
                      return <ListItem>

                        <Text>{item.fruit_name}</Text>

                    </ListItem>
```

Data sources:

```
https://reactnativecode.000webhostapp.com/FruitsList.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is when you type `Ap`, the `this.state.results` is filter to `set 2`. And you `backspace` to `A` but the `this.state.results` still in `set 2` so It could not go back to `set 1`. If you want it. You should use a `global` variable to save the results and always filter it, Example:
`

```
 filter(text){
        this.setState({ keywords: text })
        const newData = globalOfResults.filter(function(item){
             ....
        }
    }
```

`